# What is the best way to create multiple versions of my Swift 2 app to test different features?

Tags: git, github, version-control, xcode7, branch

I have a project in Xcode 7 written in Swift 2.

I am new to app development and am trying to figure out the best way to create multiple versions of the development version of my project. I basically want to have backups in case I completely screw something up so I can just use an earlier version instead of spending hours trying to figure out how to fix it.

I am trying to set up GitHub as this seems to be a pretty good way to do it, however I am still trying to figure out the specifics of creating different branches for my app and how everything works together. For instance I created a new branch of my project and went to commit to that branch and I'm not exactly sure if I should commit the automatically selected files or if I need to select additional ones. This is something I need to research.

I'd like to try and find the easiest way to do what I explained above. If anyone has any suggestions other than GitHub that would be great, otherwise if you think GitHub is the best route can you send me any helpful resources that come to mind pertaining to my goal above it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use built in git in Xcode. You can find how those it up here https://medium.com/@0xben/using-github-with-xcode-6-8208b92c7a60#.lv9l0ba4m. Then if you want to create another branch you choose Source Control -> name of your project -> New branch. If you want to switch a branch to choose Switch Branch.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need is just to setup git locally. This will enable you to create different branches, each corresponding to a feature you would like to try. Also, it will keep the history of your commits so you can checkout previous commits too. I would suggest reading [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) which is freely available. I highly recommend using command line tool and you will need only a few set of command to get started and be productive.